# Bit reversal problem

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I'm trying to figure why divide and conquer technique has this property:

for example, we count 0 to 7, then we divide them into 2 parts: [0, 2, 4, 6] and [1, 3, 5, 7]. Then we divide each of the 2 vectors into 2 parts again: [0, 4], [2, 6], [1, 5], [3, 7].

We surprisingly find that the binary of this order (0 4 2 6 1 5 3 7) is just symmetrical about (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7):

0: 000 | 000:0 
1: 001 | 100: 4 
2: 010 | 010: 2 
3: 011 | 110: 6 
4: 100 | 001: 2 
5: 101 | 101: 5 
6: 110 | 011: 3 
7: 111 | 111: 7

For even number of bits, it also holds. For example,  
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15) 
to 
(0 8 4 12 2 10 6 14 1 9 5 13 3 11 7 15)

0 : 0000 | 0000: 0 
1 : 0001 | 1000: 8 
2 : 0010 | 0100: 4 
3 : 0011 | 1100: 12 
4 : .... | .... 
5 : 
6 : 
7 : 
8 : 
9 : 
10: 
11: 
12: 
13: .... | .... 
14: 1110 | 0111: 7 
15: 1111 | 1111: 15

I can partially understand it's because the property of divide and conquer, but is there any math equation for this kind of proof - i.e. proof of divide and conquer then reorder of a set of number is the bit symmetric of the original order, given set length = 2^n?

Comment: See [here](https://www.katjaas.nl/bitreversal/bitreversal.html)

Comment: Why should this interesting question should be closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would need to be formalized better, but anyway explains what is going on.

Let $n$ be the number of digits with which we represent any number $m$ such that $0 \le m \le 2^n-1$ (so in total $2^n$ representable numbers). The binary expansion of $m$ ($b_{n-1}b_{n-2}\ldots b_1b_0$) is:

$$m = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k2^k$$

We have a sequence of $2^n$ numbers $(0,1,2,\ldots,2^n-1)$ representable with the above equation ($(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ in your example, with $n=3$).

If we apply the "divide and conquer" that you propose, the sequence that we obtain in your example is $(0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7)$. To obtain that, we can multiply by $2$ the values in the original sequence and then compute the remainder modulo $7$. This is equivalent to adding $-7$ only for numbers on the original sequence that are greater or equal to $4$, which are the only ones that have $b_2 \not = 0$. Once that we discard the bits at position $3$ or more, subtracting $-7$ is equivalent to adding $1$ (see [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)), but we need to do this only for $m \ge 4$, therefore we can just add $b_2$, because it will be $0$ for $m < 4$. Summing up we start from the binary representation $b_2b_1b_0$, multiply by $2$ to get $b_2b_1b_00$, add $b_2$ to get $b_2b_1b_0b_2$, discard the most significant $b_2$ because on position $\ge 3$ to get $b_1b_0b_2$: we have moved $b_2$ to the least significant position.

In the next step we go from $(0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7)$ to $(0,4,2,6,1,5,3,7)$. We note that $b_2$ does not move anymore because we have $4$ even numbers followed by $4$ odd numbers before and after the permutation. If we make $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$ of the numbers in $(0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7)$ and $(0,4,2,6,1,5,3,7)$ we get $(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)$ and $(0,2,1,3,0,2,1,3)$ respectively, therefore we are doing the same operation on the first and second half, working only on the two most significant bits $b_1b_0$ of $b_1b_0b_2$, and repeating the reasoning of the previous paragraph we can understand that we are swapping $b_1$ and $b_0$ to finally get $b_0b_1b_2$.

This can be extended to any number of digits $n$, for example for $n=4$ your sequence of operations is $\mathbf{b_3b_2b_1b_0}$, $\mathbf{b_2b_1b_0}b_3$, $\mathbf{b_1b_0}b_2b_3$, $b_0b_1b_2b_3$, where at each step you move and work on only the bold digits.